How to run useEffect ONLY once?
Whenever I've asked people how to run useEffect once they answer that by saying add an empty array after the function to run it once. Like the following:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hi");
}, []);

But that calls the function twice. So the output of the above example in the console would be Hi twice. But I want Hi once.
I've been using the same normal method for fetching data into my website on the first render.
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.example.com/");
    const data = await response.json();
    setData(data);
    console.log("data fetched");
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

The console shows data fetched twice and that isn't good for the performance of the website. How can I just fetch the data only once in useEffect.

Presumably you're in strict mode?

If you are using react in strict mode it will run useEffects twice. One way you can prevent this by using a useRef.
const used = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (!used.current){
    console.log("Hi");
    used.current = true;
  }
});


Using refs and "isMounted", "isFirstRender", etc... have become anti-patterns for some time now.
